# Calling embedded function in class method using pybind11

Tags: c++, python-3.x

I'm working on a c++ application that uses pybind11 to embed python and I've run into a bit of a problem when trying to call an embedded function from a class method.

to start with here are my bindings:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
#undef _DEBUG
#include <python.h>
#define _DEBUG
#else
#include <python.h>
#endif
#include <embed.h>

namespace py = pybind11;
using namespace py::literals;

void DebugInfo(std::string string_)
{
    String LogMessage_(string_.c_str());
    LOGINFO(LogMessage_);
}

PYBIND11_EMBEDDED_MODULE(Test, m) {
    m.def("DebugInfo", &DebugInfo, "Posts message to DEBUGINFO");
}
```

I could then have a .py file with:

```
import Test
test.DebugInfo("I'm a lumberjack and that's OK")
```

and it will print just fine to debug

The trouble starts when I try and call it from within a class method.

```
import Test
class PyTest(object):
    def __init__(self):
        test.DebugInfo("I'm a lumberjack and that's OK")

test = PyTest()
```

when this runs it throws an exception against cast.h specifically against line 1985 which is part of this function:

```
template <return_value_policy policy>
class unpacking_collector {
public:
    template <typename... Ts>
    explicit unpacking_collector(Ts &&...values) {
        // Tuples aren't (easily) resizable so a list is needed for collection,
        // but the actual function call strictly requires a tuple.
        auto args_list = list();
        int _[] = { 0, (process(args_list, std::forward<Ts>(values)), 0)... };
        ignore_unused(_);

        m_args = std::move(args_list);
    }

    const tuple &args() const & { return m_args; }
    const dict &kwargs() const & { return m_kwargs; }

    tuple args() && { return std::move(m_args); }
    dict kwargs() && { return std::move(m_kwargs); }

    /// Call a Python function and pass the collected arguments
    object call(PyObject *ptr) const {
        PyObject *result = PyObject_Call(ptr, m_args.ptr(), m_kwargs.ptr());
        if (!result)
            throw error_already_set();  //EXCEPTION THROWS HERE!
        return reinterpret_steal<object>(result);
    }
```

And because it's probably relevant here's how I'm calling the whole thing from my main application

```
//Start the Python Interpreter
py::scoped_interpreter guard{};
//Python variables
py::object thing_;
std::string test_py = Import_File("test.py");
auto locals = py::dict();
py::exec(test_py, py::globals(), locals);
thing_ = locals["test"].cast<py::object>();
thing_.attr("start")();
```

and the contents of test.py

```
import Test
class PyTest(object):
    def __init__(self, message = "Test Object initialized"):
        self.message = message
        iterstr = str(self.iter)
        message = self.message + iterstr
        self.iter = 0
        Test.DebugInfo(message)
    def start(self):
        self.message = "Starting Python Object"
        self.iter = self.iter + 1
        iterstr = str(self.iter)
        message = self.message + iterstr
        Test.DebugInfo(message)
    def update(self):
        self.message = "Python Object Update Cycle:"
        self.iter = self.iter + 1
        iterstr = str(self.iter)
        message = self.message + iterstr
        Test.DebugInfo(message)

test = PyTest()
```

I'm not sure if I've run into a limitation of pybind11, a bug in it, or if I've just screwed the whole thing up.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This was also filed as an issue with `pybind11` here: https://github.com/pybind/pybind11/issues/1452

I came across both this SO and the issue, but I figured this out. Copying it here for anyone who stumbles across this first in the future

Basically, you don't actually want a blank `py::dict` for `locals`; it will cause all sorts of problems. If you look embedding sample code from the docs or the tests, the `locals` value always copies the global scope.

See:

```
* https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/embedding.html

* https://github.com/pybind/pybind11/blob/master/tests/test_embed/test_interpreter.cpp#L57
```

Your options are to copy the global scope, or, in this case, simply don't pass in a `locals`

```cpp
py::scoped_interpreter guard{}; 
auto globals = py::globals();
py::exec(test_py, globals);
thing_ = globals["Object"].cast<py::object>(); 
thing_.attr("start")();
```

It looks like that in the case of top-level code (not inside any module), the `globals` variable holds the values at this scope.

Answer (score 1):

So after some experimentation I discovered that the problem is caused by pybind not being able to detect an imported module outside of the scope of the function.

```
import foo

def bar():
  foo.func()
```

will always cause an error. However,

```
def bar():
  import foo
  foo.func()
```

will function as intended.